# scp documents from server from inside Bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scp

I normally use `scp` like so:

```
myUser@myMachine:~/myapp$ scp devops@myserver.org:/path/to/bin/*.derp .
devops@myserver.org's password: ********
herp1.derp                                100%  732     0.7KB/s   00:00    
herp2.derp                                100%  215     0.2KB/s   00:00    
herp3.derp                                100%  682     0.7KB/s   00:00    
myUser@myMachine:~/myapp$
```

I now want to write a Bash script that, among other things, does this for me, but where the password is stored in the script, and the script doesn't query the user to enter it:

```
sh dostuff.sh
```

Just running that should `scp` all the `*.derp` files to the user's local directory.

So I ask: **how can I supply the password to `scp` from inside my script?** Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks but that question is actually about `rsync` not `scp` (it's improperly titled)

Comment: No it's not. The question never mentions rsync.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of hardcoding password in a shell script, use SSH keys, its easier and secure.

```
$ scp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa devops@myserver.org:/path/to/bin/*.derp .
```

assuming your private key is at `~/.ssh/id_rsa`

To generate a public / private key pair :

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

The above will generate 2 files, `~/.ssh/id_rsa` (private key) and `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` (public key)

To setup the SSH keys for usage (one time task) :
Copy the contents of `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` and paste in a new line of `~devops/.ssh/authorized_keys` in a new line in `myserver.org` server. If `~devops/.ssh/authorized_keys` doesn't exist, feel free to create it.

A lucid how-to guide is available [here](http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html).

Comment: Thanks @galuano1 (+1) - what would the file look like at `path/to/my/private/key`, and how do I generate it? Thanks again!